# How to extract information about colors and parenting relationshps from text

Tags: python, information-extraction, text-processing

How can we apply basic techniques of text processing (tokenization, POS, stemming, named entities recognition, constituting parse, dependency parse and coreference) to extract the following information:

- which is the most cited clothes color in the text?
- detect the parenting relationships between persons cited in the text?